# Selecting random points based on the distance between them

Tags: qgis, point, select

I have to select a random set of points from a point shapefile based on the following rule:

```
"no two points can be within 1km of each other"
```

Here is an example:

[image: Point selection example]

Ideally, I'd like to do this through the algorithms already present in QGIS, but if I having to do that through scripts it should not be a problem.

Comment: Consider the fact that if you select the middle one, then neither of the ones on the sides could be selected. That would be invalid since it's not the maximum number. Now consider how that fact scales across hundreds or thousands of points. Hopefully, this helps you see the complexity of the problem you're trying to solve; you'll need to test and eliminate a *lot* of combinations to find the true maximum. I'd be looking for graph theory algorithms.

Comment: You're right, and now that i think about it it might have been asking too much. I think im going to remove the maximizing part to make it more reasonable.

Comment: It's quite easy to do that with python scipy. Ex. select random point, than, calculate distances between each points, select point ~1km (minimum from greater than), and repeat it.

Answer (score 2):

### Basic idea(s)

1. Create a 1km buffer around the points and dissolve it.
2. Select points with one of these options:

- Assign the buffer's id to the points. Randomly select one point per buffer, based on buffer id.
- From the group of points with the same buffer id select the one with the smallest point id
- Select a point without using id, but location, e.g. select the most central one: select the point closest to the centroid of the buffer polygon (see below for an expression how to do that).

### Maximize the number of selected points

With an iterative approach, you could maximize the number of selected points:

- As you can see in the screenshot, in the upper left, there is a buffer containing 7 points more or less in a line.
- In one run, one point is selected.
- For a second run, exclude all points within a radius of 1 km from already selected points (again create a buffer around selected points and include only points outside these buffers) and repeat with the remaining points as long as there are points left.

### How to implement the selction

To get the point closest to the centroid, use the following expression (cf. screenshot):

```
closest_point (
    collect_geometries (
        overlay_contains (
            'points',
            $geometry
        )
    ),
    centroid ($geometry)
)
```

### Screenshot

*Initial points (white), dissolved one km-buffer (blue) and one point per buffer selected (red star):*
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try it with the following workflow for example in QGIS:

1. create a 1x1km polygon grid
2. join the grid polygons to the points (spatial join)
3. use random selection within subset (vector/research tools); use the polygon id

Comment: On this case,  there still might be points closer then 1km to wach other selected, when both points are close to the grid's border.